# Why is the p tag showing up in my webpage?

Tags: html

I want help with the following code

`<p kawai manga kun san uwu owo~chan</>`
I want to make an anime website. Please give me code.
Help me Uwu~~

Comment: That is not valid HTML. Your opening paragraph element is incorrect. From what you wrote, I believe you probably want to change it to this:

`<p>kawai manga kun san uwu owo~chan</p>`

You can learn more about paragraph elements here:

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_paragraphs.asp

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is this...

```
<p>kawai manga kun san uwu owo~chan</p>
```